# Working with inequalities

Tags: calculus, inequality

While working with some inequalities I've noticed that combining the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality with some others we get the following:

$|x|+|y|\ge|x+y|\ge |x-y|\ge||x|-|y||\ge|x|-|y|$

Does this inequality hold, or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|x| + |y| \ge |x| - |y|$ holds for all real numbers, but your derivation
of that inequality is invalid:
$$
 |x+y| \ge |x - y|
$$
does not hold if $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs (e.g. $x=1$, $y=-1$).

As you figured out in the meantime, removing $|x+y|$ or
$|x-y|$ from the inequality chain makes it correct:
$$
|x|+|y|\ge |x+y|\ge||x|-|y||\ge|x|-|y| \\
|x|+|y|\ge |x-y|\ge||x|-|y||\ge|x|-|y|
$$
which the same inequalities via the substitution $y \to -y$.

(Of course you don't need those triangle inequalities in order
to prove $|x| + |y| \ge |x| - |y|$, as [@Ant demonstrated](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2147856/42969).)

Comment: Yes, this makes sense, any ideas on how the inequality should be? Maybe it should be in two parts?

Comment: @Michael: What inequality? What are you actually trying to prove? There is no relationship between $|x+y|$ and $|x-y|$ which holds for all real numbers.

Comment: So to sort things out here it goes somethin like this right?: $|x|+|y|\ge|x+y|\ge||x|-|y||\ge|x|-|y|$
$|x|+|y|\ge |x-y|\ge||x|-|y||\ge|x|-|y|$

Comment: @Michael: Yes, those inequality chains are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality is equivalent to $$|y| \ge -|y|$$, that is $$|y| \ge 0$$

So yes, it holds

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure how it is equivalent to that

Comment: @Michael Do you agree that $|y|\ge-|y|$? Then add $jx|$ to both sides.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $|x|+|y|\ge|x+y|\ge |x-y|\ge||x|-|y||\ge|x|-|y|$ :

1. $|x|+|y|\ge|x+y|$ by the triangle inequality

---

2. $|x+y|\ge |x-y|$ is false.

---

3. $|x-y|\ge||x|-|y||$ by reverse triangle inequality

---

4. $||x|-|y||\ge|x|-|y|$ is of the form $|x| \ge x$, which is clearly true

Comment: (2) is wrong for $x=1, y=-1$.

Comment: Your revised version is not correct either: $x=2, y=-3$.

Comment: @MartinR *sigh*.  Yep.